# run a function after two async functions have finished

Tags: javascript

When my page loads it runs two async functions. What I would like to do is after both functions have finished is to run another function? What is the best way to do this? I have been reading about Promises but not sure if that is a good solution?

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async () => {


let data1 = await get_func1();
let data2 = await get_func2();

// after get_func1 & get_func2 have run I want to run a function called func3

});
```

Comment: just put it where your comment is? You're already waiting for both functions to finish. If func1 and func2 are independent, you can await them in parallel using a `Promise.all` construction but either your new code just goes where your comment is right now.

Comment: Since you are `await`-ing both `get_func1` and `get_func2`, you can simply call the function you need after those call. The code will run `get_func1` and wait for it to finish. Then call `get_func2`, wait for it to finish. Then, it will run the function you want.

Comment: If you want both `get_func1` and `get_func2` to run simultaneously, you can call `await Promise.all([get_func1(), get_func2()])`, and then call your function. Both async function will be run at the same time, and when both are done, your function will be called.

Comment: A side note, your `await get_func1` and `await get_func2` are executed in "sequental" order, one after another, you can fire them both in "parallel" with `let [data1, data2] = await Promise.all([get_func1(), get_func2()]);` so it might be a bit faster.

Comment: In addition to @Nicolas 's comment, if first function's returned value is not going to be used for calling second function, then `Promise.all` is the way to go. I wanted to mention this to help you decide.

Answer (score -3):

Try this

```js
const myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  // Something
});

await myPromise()
```

An other example :

```js
const promiseA = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve(777);
});
// At this point, "promiseA" is already settled.
promiseA.then((val) => console.log("asynchronous logging has val:", val));
console.log("immediate logging");

// produces output in this order:
// immediate logging
// asynchronous logging has val: 777
```

Doc : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise